# Improve this javascript code: It displays hidden text and highlights the selected page number

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code ([http://jsbin.com/isexez/5/edit](http://jsbin.com/isexez/3/edit)) functions as expected:
(1) it displays the page selected; and
(2) it highlights the number of the selected page.

I would appreciate help in improving it.

I am in the process of writing an ebook (http://www.keepcount.net/ebook/01-09/02_tricks.html) and need to improve this code before I get back to my writing.

*  Here's my jQuery code as suggested by @Gisborne ***
See also  jsbin.com/iduxol/2/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Need to add http: to link in following line -->
<script class="jsbin" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

<style>
.nodisp {  display:none;  } 
.highlight { background:yellow; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- When page numbers (p1 & p2) are clicked, page's text is displayed and page number remains highlighted -->
<span class="pageNumbers">
<a id="1"> p1 </a>
<a id="2"> p2 </a>
</span>

<!-- Show page 1 initially -->  
<div id="pg1" class="page">
   text on page 1
</div>

<!-- Hide page 2 initially  -->
<div id="pg2" class="page nodisp">
   quiz on page 2
</div>

<script>
  $("span.pageNumbers a").click(function () {

  // Remove all highlighting
    $("span.pageNumbers a").removeClass("highlight");

  // Add highlighting to clicked page number
    $(this).addClass("highlight");

  // Hide all text
    $("div.page").hide();

  // Show text corresponding to clicked page number
    $("#pg"+ $(this).attr('id')).show();

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with several changes, however most of these require the latest jQuery as well as making use of HTML5.  Here's why.

First of all, in HTML5 you have a data attribute that is easily accessible via jQuery .data().  This means you can store massive amounts of element related data on each specific element and recall it as needed.  Which is why I rewrote your HTML as follow:

> HTML

```
<!-- When page numbers (p1 & p2) are clicked, page's text is displayed and page number remains highlighted.
     Here I replaced the id attribute with a data attribute that contains each pages exact id
     You may also noticed the change in ID's simply to help better represent what pg they correlate too.  
     This will be used later to make dynamic call on load to start things off on the right foot -->
<span class="pageNumbers">
    <a id="a-1" data-page="#pg1" href="javascript:void(0)"> p1 </a>
    <a id="a-2" data-page="#pg2" href="javascript:void(0)"> p2 </a>
</span>

<!-- Show page 1 initially -->  
<div id="pg1" class="page">
   text on page 1
</div>

<!-- Hide page 2 initially  -->
<div id="pg2" class="page nodisp">
   quiz on page 2
</div>
```

Secondly, one of the main purposes of jQuery is to "Do more, write less", thus they have many different ways to initiate an action, but the idea is to find the least amount of code to do it in.  Thus I make use of the sibling function in order to write less and do more.  See the following:

> Script

```
$(function() {
    $(".pageNumbers a").on("click", function(e) {
        //  Add highlight to the element clicked and remove highlighting from its siblings
        $(this).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight");
        //  Make use of our data attribute to show the correct page and hide the siblings
        $($(this).data('page')).show().siblings(".page").hide();
    });

    //  Finally, dynamically click first page to start things off for the user and provide proper highlighting and showing of text
    $("#a-1").click();
});​
```

See working jsFiddle 

## HERE


More instruction found on script section there.

Comment: Thanks @spYk3HH. I guess it will makes things easier in the long run to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas:

- Use either tab or, preferably, 4-spaces for indention consistently. Right now the indention is all screwy on JSBin.
- Put *all* your variable declarations at the top, even if you don't define them yet. This'll prevent any confusion from [variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting).
- Since `null` is a falsy value, you can change `document.getElementById(...) !== null` to `document.getElementById(...)` to check for the existence of an element in you `if` statements.
- Space out your `if` statements (so `if (...)` instead of `if(...)`.)
- Maybe think about using jQuery? It'll make working with events and elements much easier than using the DOM directly. So for example, hiding all the pages could be written as easy as: `$('div').hide()`.

That's all I have time for now!